# CUDA: Method of partitioning *huge* problems?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, partitioning, gpgpu

All this CUDA lark is head-melting in its power, but something I've been wondering about is the hard-limits on 1d block/grid dimensions (usually 512/65535 respectively).

When dealing with problems that are much larger in their scope (in the order of billions), is there an automated programmatic way of effectively setting a 'queue' through a kernel, or is it a case of manual slicing and dicing?

How does everyone deal with problem-partitioning?

Comment: Don't we already have queues in CUDA by default?

Comment: The same three people keep appearing in all my questions! (not complaining) I see queues mentioned in passing all over the place but with no idiot-proof examples.

Comment: Kernel launches are asynchronous, and two consecutive kernel launches (on the same stream) means that the second will be "queued". In fact, I use queue as an alias for stream.

Comment: But theres no 'magical' queue.push(kernel<<<>>>())? I've got no problem with DIY, but reinventing the wheel isn't all that reliable :D

Comment: No there is. You can queue up as many kernel calls as you like - the launch action is non-blocking. For more than one stream, the stream id becomes part of the kernel launch, ie. kernel<<<grid,block,smem,stream>>>(). By default, everything goes into stream 0, but if you use multiple streams, you can overlap copy with kernel execution, and on Fermi run multiple kernel at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 basic ways of partitioning your data, so that you can work on it using CUDA:

1. Break data down into contiguous **chunks**, such that each thread works on one chunk.
2. Each thread nibbles at one element of data. When all threads are done, they shift themselves by numberOfThreads and repeat again.

I have explained these techniques with simple examples [here](http://choorucode.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/cuda-work-allocation-techniques/). Method 2 is typically easier to code and work with for most tasks.

Answer (score 1):

If one dimensional grids are too small, just use two dimensional (or three dimensional on Fermi with CUDA 4.0) grids instead. Dimensionality in grid and block layouts is really only for convenience - it makes the execution space look like the sort of common data parallel inputs spaces programmers are used to working with (matrices, grids, voxels, etc). But it is only a very small abstraction away from the underlying simple linear numbering scheme that can handle over 10^12 unique thread IDs within a single kernel launch.

In grids, ordering is column major, so if you had a 1D grid problem before, the "unique, 1D thread index" was calculated as:

```
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
```

which has a theoretical upper limit of 512 * 65535 = 33553920 unique threads. The equivalent 2D grid problem is only a simple extension of the 1D case

```
size_t tidx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
size_t tid = tidx + blockIdx.y * blockDim.x * GridDim.x;
```

which has a theoretical upper limit of 512 * 65535 * 65535 = 2198956147200 unique threads. Fermi will let you add a third dimension to the grid, also of 65535 maximum size, which gives up to about 10^17 threads in a single execution grid. Which is rather a lot.

Comment: I was under the impression that maximal grid dimensions where literally that; the max for that dimension assuming the others were unitary. Thanks you for your (as always) clear answer, but taking an extreme case where 2^9*2^16*2*16 STILL isn't enough? (Think streaming reductions of intermediate datasets that are generated, discarded and reduced on the gpu)

Comment: Well, then you have to devise some sort of partitioning scheme to divide the input space up and either process it sequentially, or scatter it across multiple devices. But in practice, the device memory will be exhausted well before the available thread count. The current largest GPU only ships with 6Gb of memory - that is only 10^9 threads, assuming each thread needs to operate on at least unique 32 bit type from global memory per kernel call.